# Slow xcode 4 debugger

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4

I've some issues with the Xcode 4 debugger. While it was working fine before, now I can't run more than 1 build before restarting my xcode. When I run a second build for example after changing some codes the debugger could take like 30 mins and more before showing "build succeeded!" with iphone simulator launch. And in such cases, pressing "stop" button does not stop debugger. So, I've to close xcode and start it again. Now, after many xcode restarts I'm fed up especially as I don't know why it happens. Any idea to help ?

Comment: There are quite a few already on this topic. Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225603/xcode-4-4-0-1-became-extremely-slow-and-kills-my-hard-drive) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355667/xcode-4-slow-performance)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simulator could still be running, chewing up a large chunk of your CPU, interfering with the compile, and the app restart inside it. Stop your app in the simulator before re-compiling. There must be a way to configure that, but i dont know it. Hope that is your issue (i have had it).

ps. state your config next time (Dev box specifics, XCode version, simulated iOS version).